# Matrix concatenation in matlab

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have a 3 * 3 matrix, how to get a matrix b (2 * 2) without row 2 and col 2?
I am trying to write a script to generate a cofactor matrix in matlab.

Thank you!

```
function b = cofactormatrix(a)
for i = 1:3
    for j = 1:3
        concatenated = a
        concatenated(i,:) = []
        concatenated(:,j) = []
        b(i,j) = (-1 ^ (i+j))*det(concatenated)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if X is a 3x3 matrix to delete the second column do:

`X(:,2) = []`

Then, to delete the remaining second row do:

`X(2,:) = []`

this should do the trick. hope this helps, Scott

Comment: function b = cofactormatrix(a)
for i = 1:3
    for j = 1:3
        concatenated = a
        concatenated(i,:) = []
        concatenated(:,j) = []
        b(i,j) = (-1 ^ (i+j))*det(concatenated)
    end
end

Comment: concatenated = a gives an error of not enough arguments. Please help. Thanks

Comment: @Ra1nWarden Sorry, I was not quick on the draw to respond to your comments but it seems you have everything figured out(?). Let me know if there is anything else.